# Find the transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B = \{2x, 3x+x^2, -1\}, B'=\{1, 1+x, 1+x+x^2\}$
I need to find the transformation matrix from $B$ to $B'$.

I know that:   $$(ax^2 +bx +c)_B = ({b-3c \over 2}, c, -a)$$
$$(ax^2 +bx +c)_{B'} = (a-b, b-c, c)$$

How to proceed using this info in order to find the transformation matrix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $B_c=(1,x,x^2)$ the canonical basis. Let $P_{B\to B_c}$ the transformation matrix from $B_c$ to $B$ and $P_{B'\to B_c}$ the transformation matrix from $B_c$ to $B'$ then the transformation matrix from $B$ to $B'$ is
$$P_{B'\to B}=P_{B'\to B_c}\left(P_{B\to B_c}\right)^{-1}$$

Comment: I'll give it a try. Is that the most efficient way?

Comment: Surely this is the most efficient way!

Comment: Wait a minute, is $B' \rightarrow B$ is the right notation?

Comment: I didn't know this fine way, Sami. +1